# Get rows product (multiplication)

Tags: mysql, sql

SO,

**The problem**

I have an issue with rows multiplication. In SQL, there is a `SUM()` function which calculates sum for some field for set of rows. I want to get multiplication, i.e. for table

```
+------+
| data |
+------+
|    2 |
|   -1 |
|    3 |
+------+
```

that will be `2*(-1)*3 = -6` as a result. I'm using *DOUBLE* data type for storing my data values.

**My approach**

From school math it is known that `log(A x B) = log(A) + log(B)` - so that could be used to created desired expression like:

```
SELECT
  IF(COUNT(IF(SIGN(`col`)=0,1,NULL)),0,
    IF(COUNT(IF(SIGN(`col`)<0,1,NULL))%2,-1,1)
    *
    EXP(SUM(LN(ABS(`col`))))) as product
FROM `test`;
```

-here you see weakness of this method - since `log(X)` is undefined when `X<=0` - I need to count negative signs before calculating whole expression. Sample data and query for this is given [in this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96f5c/1).
Another weakness is that we need to find if there is 0 among column values (Since it is a sample, in real situation I'm going to select product for some subset of table rows with some condition(s) - i.e. I can not simply remove 0-s from my table, because result zero product is a valid and expected result for some rows subsets)

**Specifics**

And now, finally, my question main part: how to handle situation when we have expression like: `X*Y*Z` and here `X < MAXF`, `Y<MAXF`, but `X*Y>MAXF` and `X*Y*Z<MAXF` - so we have possible data type overflow (here `MAXF` is limit for *double* MySQL data type). The sample is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f67d/1). Query above works well, but can I always be sure that it will handle that properly? I.e. may be there is another case with overflow issue when some sub-products causing overflow, but entire product is ok (without overflow).

Or may be there is another way to find rows product? Also, in table there possibly be millions of records (`-1.1<X<=1.1` mainly, but probably with values such as 100 or 1000 - i.e. high enough to overflow *DOUBLE* if multiplied with certain quantity if we have an issue that I've described above) - may be calculating via `log` will be slow?

Comment: What data types are you using?

Comment: If you need this type of calculations often, I suggest you store the signs (with -1 and 1) and the logarithms in separate columns (and remove all rows with 0s)

Comment: @ppeterka66 actually, it will not affect the result (since all data types have their limits). I'm using _DOUBLE_ data type (see fiddle, but I'll update, thank you)

Comment: @ypercube hm why remove 0-s? it is a valid value. I'm going to select product not for entire table, of cause - but with some condition. Also, values can change/be created/deleted - e.t.c. - it's a normal table field

Comment: @Vatev what do you mean 'emulate'? I want to be sure that it will not be an overflow when the entire product is ok, but some subproducts are not ok.

Comment: `X*Y>MAXF` overflowing is not a problem for you because you are calculating `LN(X)+LN(Y)`. Your fiddle seems to be working fine :) You might have problems with loss of precision, but I'm not really competent to analyze for those...

Comment: @Vatev well, this is good point- thanks (may be that should be an answer to first part - about overflow) - I was hesitating in this because of `EXP` part, but, well, if log-s are ok, it seems you're right, overflow will not happen

Comment: DOUBLE is still weak. Precision error adds up very quickly. And gets worsened with EXP.

Comment: @ppeterka66 your point is correct. It was not an issue for my question, but now I'm thinking about that, thank you

Comment: Don't forget about possibility of writing your own aggregate function as UDF. It's tricky to do it right, but you have a lot of freedom doing so - you are limited only by your C/C++ skill. Perfomance wise it would be the best choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need this type of calculations often, I suggest you store the signs and the logarithms in separate columns.

The signs can be stored as `1` (for positives), `-1` (for negatives) and `0` (for zero.)

The logarithm can be assigned for zero as `0` (or any other value) but it should not be used in calculations.

Then the calculation would be:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE <condition> AND datasign = 0)
         THEN 0
         ELSE (SELECT 1-2*(SUM(datasign=-1)%2) FROM test WHERE <condition>)
    END AS resultsign,

    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE <condition> AND datasign = 0)
         THEN -1            -- undefined log for result 0
         ELSE (SELECT SUM(datalog) FROM test WHERE <condition> AND datasign <> 0)
    END AS resultlog
  ;
```

This way, you have no overflow problems. You can check the `resultlog` if it exceeds some limits or just try to calculate `resultdata = resultsign * EXP(resultlog)` and see if an error is thrown.

Comment: Hw.. to store sign separately - that could be good. Only problem is - if I want to change values often enough, I will need to change signs to (i.e. take care of this). Storing 0 as sign.. How? I.e. I should have some value in actual column, then if I have 0 as sign - so it is 0? May be too complicated.

Comment: If the value (in column `data`) is changed, then the additional columns (`datasign` and `datalog`) will have to be modified accordingly (maybe with triggers or whatever.) I don't see how 0 is a problem. Positive numbers have 1 as sign, negatives have -1 and zero has 0.

Comment: I think removing the 0 rows would not serve any good: it is a valid value, and if there is a 0, the end result would be 0 too. OP explicitly stated this in the question. However, storing the signs as -1, 0, 1 would be great. Just have to count the 0s, and the -1s, and if there is at least 1 that is 0, the result is 0, and the parity of the counted -1s gives the end result... Also, if something: storing the LOG values would really help performance!

Comment: @ypercube - Well, I'm thinking about that now. (May be I'll create siple trigger for that) - thank you again. As for zeros. Hm. `datalog` for them will be a problem

Comment: @ppeterka66 If it's a valid value, I agree. I will remove that part.

Comment: The only performance improvement I can imagine from this would come from pre-calculating the log's for a DECIMAL type (which would probably be fast enough anyway, so it has to be tested), otherwise the entire thing is still IO bound, and all of this is just premature optimization.

Comment: @ypercube saw your edit. Why `-1` is impossible for logarithm? It changes from `-INF` to `+INF`

Comment: Oh boy, silly me. Yes, any value is possible for logarithm. Corrected.

Comment: This was useful for me. Other answers also were good, but this idea was the best from proposed to me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this would work...

```
SELECT IF(MOD(COUNT(data < 0),2)=1
        , EXP(SUM(LOG(data)))*-1
        , EXP(SUM(LOG(data))))
          x 
  FROM my_table;
```

Comment: Upvoted, since it is another way (however, it's not a full answer, but thank you for your time anyway)

Comment: Seems brilliantly simple! However there is the issue with 0. And I feel this can be simplified, using the same thinking: `SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(data)))*((-0.5+MOD(COUNT(data < 0),2))*2) x 
  FROM my_table;` This way you don't need an IF, and `((-0.5+MOD(COUNT(data < 0),2))*2)` should be either 1 or -1. For 0 values, it would be quicker to issue a select from the app triggering this query, as if there is at elast one 0 in all the data, it makes the result 0 regardless of all the other numbers. (The ABS thing was a mistake, I deleted that from this comment...)

Comment: Yeah, I *think* ppeterka may have cracked it! (Assuming that really is the way in which zeros are to be handled)

Answer (score 1):

This question is a remarkable one in the sea of low quality ones. Thank you, even reading it was a pleasure.

**Precision**

The `exp(log(a)+log(b))` idea is a good one in itself. However, after reading [**"What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), make sure you use [**`DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) data types to be sure you are using [Precision Math](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math.html), or else your values will be surprisingly inaccurate. For a couple of million rows, errors can add up very quickly! `DECIMAL` (as per the MySQL doc) has a maximum of 65 digits precision, while for example 64bit IEEE754 floating point values have only up to 16 digits (log10(2^52) = 15.65) precision!

**Overflow**

As per the [relevant part of the MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html):

> - **Integer** overflow results in silent wraparound.
> - **DECIMAL** overflow results in a truncated result and a warning.
> - **Floating-point** overflow produces a NULL result. Overflow for some operations can result in +INF, -INF, or NaN.

So you can detect floating point overflow if it would ever happen.

Sadly, if a series of operations would result in a correct value, fitting into the data type used, but at least one subresult in the process of calculations would not, then you won't get the correct value at the end.

**Performance**

Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Try it, and if it is slow, take the appropriate actions. Doing this might not be lightning quick, but still might be quicker than getting all the results, and doing it on the application server. Only measurements can decide which gets to be quicker...

Comment: @Strawberry could you be as kind as to elaborate on why my answer misses the point? Are these irrelevant what I wrote? Are these not helpful? Yes, I did not go into details on the immediate issue with the 0s and the negative values - but that was not my intent.

Comment: Thanks you, I agree about _premature optimization_ . But I have only one way to do that (for now - since I have no other ideas), so if it will be slow - I have no choice, may be. Thanks to @Vatev I'm quite sure that overflow will not be the case if entire product is good.

Comment: Well, clearly Alma disagrees (with me), so you can have your point back. ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry hey don't do that, the points are just fake ego boosters... If you have something, don't hold back, I'd be the happiest to learn I was wrong at some point. Being dumb and knowing it is _way better_ than the same without knowing... :)

Comment: @Strawberry not totally disagree, may be it's another point of view. Anyway, now I'm thinking about precision.